# limit of the mollifying sequence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an $L^1(\mathbb{R}^2; \mathbb{R})$ function. Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set.
Let $\eta: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),$ with support in $[-1,1]$ such that $\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}\eta(x)dx=1.$ Then consider the following limit
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{\epsilon}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}
\int\limits_{A} f(x,y)\eta\left(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}\right)dy dx.
\end{eqnarray}
What is the value of the limit? How to prove it.

P.S: Define $\eta_{\epsilon}(x):=\frac{1}{\epsilon}\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon}).$ Then $\eta_{\epsilon} \rightarrow \delta_0.$
So, I think the limit is,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{A} f(x,x)dx.
\end{eqnarray}
is it correct? How to prove it?

Comment: if you want $\eta_{\epsilon} \rightarrow \delta_0$, then you need to define $\eta_{\epsilon}(x):=\frac1\epsilon\eta(\frac{x}{\epsilon})$. Right now $\eta_{\epsilon} \rightarrow0$ almost everywhere, which means that the limit of the double integral equals $0$ right now. (Also, what is $A$?)

Comment: @Greg Martin..yes you are right.. I have made the necessary changes...Thanks for the comment. Is the result true now? Or do we need some more regularity assumption on the set A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change variables $\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}\rightarrow z$ then
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\epsilon}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}
\int\limits_{A} f(x,y)\eta\left(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}\right)dy dx\\=-
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}
\int\limits_{\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}x-\frac{1}{\epsilon}A\right)\cap [-1,1]} f(x,x-\epsilon z)\eta\left(z\right)dz dx
\end{eqnarray}
which converges by the dominated convergence theorem to
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,x)
\left( -\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} 
\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\mathbb{1}_{\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}x-\frac{1}{\epsilon}A\right)\cap [-1,1]}(z)
\eta\left(z\right)dz\right)
dx
\end{eqnarray}
Since $\eta$ is compactly supported in $[-1,1]$,
the inner integral converges to a number uniformly in $x$.
If we know that $[-1,1]\subset A$ we get a nicer limit:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{\epsilon}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}
\int\limits_{A} f(x,y)\eta\left(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}\right)dy dx=
\frac{1}{\epsilon}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)\eta\left(\frac{x-y}{\epsilon}\right)dy dx
\\=
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,x-\epsilon z)\eta\left(z\right)dz dx
\end{eqnarray}
which converges by the dominated convergence theorem to
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,x)
dx\,\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}} 
\eta\left(z\right)dz=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}}f(x,x)
dx.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: I think there is no minus, (as change of variable formula gives modulus of jacobian) and inner integral as a function of x converges to characteristic function of the set A..please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Yes, correct, but we then need to reorient the limit of integration in the "right" direction.